# Как сравнить начало ссылки регулярным выражением?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, ссылки

**Здравствуйте!**

Задача такая:
Необходимо сравнить ссылку содержащуюся в `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` с шаблоном, в шаблоне хочу указать, что ссылка должна начинаться с по шаблону а заканчиваться не важно как

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(preg_match('http://yarportal.ru/topic551948', $url))
```

Но ни чего не получается не знаком с регулярными выражениями, проблема ваще!

**Подскажите как правильно составить выражение для моей цели!**

**Спасибо!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('-^ваше_начало-', $url)
```

Циркумфлекс (^) указывает на то, что в этом месте находится начало строки. Поэтому с регуляркой, которая начинается с циркумфлекса, совпадут только те строки, которые начинаются так же.

Если модифицировать конкретно ваш пример, то там нужно только добавить этот циркумфлекс и добавить символы начала/конца шаблона (подробнее [здесь](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)):

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(preg_match('-^http://yarportal.ru/topic551948-', $url))
```

Однако, если у вас есть точная строка, совпадение с которой надо проверить, можно для этого не привлекать регулярки вообще:

```
if (strpos($url, 'http://yarportal.ru/xxx') === 0) { // обратите внимание на три символа "равно", без них код будет работать некорректно
    // код
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Друг! Всё супер!

Comment: @Fike - с вашими ограничителями можно писать няшные регэкспы =)

`preg_match(('-^_^-', $str);`

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, должно сработать

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(preg_match('/^http:\/\/yarportal.ru\/topic551948.*/i', $url))
```